# extract the structure of a letter

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, catextlayer

Say I have the letter 'a'. My objective is to redraw the letter using 'little colored flowers'. How do I extract the path/structure/blueprint of a letter in order to use it as a path for my custom draw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this article: [Low-level text rendering](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/Glyph.aspx). The long second listing outlines the use of the `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph()` function. You probably don't need to include all the setup that takes place in that listing if you just want to convert a single glyph rather than multiple lines of text.

Comment: actually I want to convert as much text as needed